# allocate memory and read input from file to arrays of structures

Tags: c, file, memory-management, structure

I have question about reading data from file to structures
when I tried to run this code i get unhandled exception Access violation reading location 0xcccccce0, The error occur inside the getData function, Why am I getting this error, how Should I fix the code ?

this is my input file

```
4
A,10
B,12
C,60
D,120
tutorY
```

my intention in the getData function was to first read the first line to get then number 4, then use that number to allocate for student structure and then read the next four lines of the file in to student structure fields and then read the last line into tutorname feild in the TUTOR structure.

thank in advance

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include "queue.h"
    #include "stack.h"

    #define RECORDS_SIZE 100
    #define NAME_SIZE    20

    typedef struct Student
    {
        char nameStudent[NAME_SIZE];
        int  TimeIn;
        int  TimeUpdate;
    }STUDENT;

    typedef struct TUTOR
    {
        char nameTutor[NAME_SIZE];
        int TutorTIme;
        STUDENT *ptr;
    }TUTOR;


    QUEUE *queue1;
    STACK *stack1;

    void getData(STUDENT *studentArr[RECORDS_SIZE], TUTOR tutorArr[1]);

    int main (void)
    {

        STUDENT *studentArr[RECORDS_SIZE];
        TUTOR tutorArr[1];
        FILE *fp = NULL;

        getData(studentArr, tutorArr);

        return 0;
    }


    void getData(STUDENT *studentArr[RECORDS_SIZE], TUTOR tutorArr[1])
    {
        FILE *fp;
        char fileName[NAME_SIZE];
        char buffer[RECORDS_SIZE];
        int first = 0;
        int count = 1;

        printf("Enter file name: ");
        gets(fileName);
        fp = fopen(fileName, "r");
        if (fp == NULL)
        {
           printf("Error! The file does not exist!\n");
        }

        fscanf(fp,"%d",&first);
        *studentArr = (STUDENT*) malloc(first*sizeof(STUDENT));
        while( fgets(buffer, first +1, fp) != NULL)
        {          
           if (count <= first)
           {
              sscanf(buffer, "%[,]%d", studentArr[count]->nameStudent, studentArr[count]->TimeIn);
              printf("%s,%d", studentArr[count]->nameStudent, studentArr[count]->TimeIn);  
           }
           else
              sscanf(buffer, "%s", tutorArr[count].nameTutor);
               count++;
        }

        return;
    }
```

Comment: lot of errors in getData functions. For example  in these statements while( gets(buffer, first +1, fp) != NULL)  {    if (count <= first)      in gets second argument is max buffer size. without modifying count your are comparing it. structure pointer usage also all wrong

Comment: `... getData(STUDENT *studentArr[RECORDS_SIZE], ...)` and then `*studentArr = malloc(...)`? Are you sure? What about `getData(STUDENT **studentArr, ..)` instead? (you call it with `getData(&students, ...)` where students will be `STUDENT *students;`).

Comment: I edited the code count is incrementing now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fix like this

```
void getData(STUDENT **studentArr, TUTOR tutorArr[1]);//change

int main (void)
{

    STUDENT *studentArr;//change
    TUTOR tutorArr[1];
    FILE *fp = NULL;//not use

    getData(&studentArr, tutorArr);//change

    return 0;
}


void getData(STUDENT **studentArr, TUTOR tutorArr[1])
{
    FILE *fp;
    char fileName[NAME_SIZE];
    char buffer[RECORDS_SIZE];
    int first = 0;
    int count = 1;

    printf("Enter file name: ");
    gets(fileName);//has risk
    fp = fopen(fileName, "r");
    if (fp == NULL)
    {
       printf("Error! The file does not exist!\n");
       return;//add, can't continue
    }

    fscanf(fp,"%d\n",&first);//add, consumption '\n'
    *studentArr = (STUDENT*) malloc(first*sizeof(STUDENT));
    while( fgets(buffer, RECORDS_SIZE, fp) != NULL)//change buffer size
    {          
       if (count <=first)//
       {
          sscanf(buffer, "%[^,],%d", (*studentArr)[count-1].nameStudent, &(*studentArr)[count-1].TimeIn);//add, `,` and -1 to count is 1 origin, `&` need for "%d" 
          printf("%s,%d\n", (*studentArr)[count-1].nameStudent, (*studentArr)[count-1].TimeIn);  
          ++count;//need count up
       }
       else
          sscanf(buffer, "%s", tutorArr[0].nameTutor);
    }

    return;//need allocate record size return to main
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There's a couple of problems I have spotted.

1. The first fscanf reading first will read the first number then leave the rest of the line ("\n") to be picked up by the first call to fgets
2. More importantly, studentArr is an array of pointers, presumably one element for each student, but the malloc allocates only the first pointer in sudentArr, all the others contain garbage, which is causing the access violation.

Comment: how should i change it to make it allocate for all elements? I tried this studentArr =  malloc(first*sizeof(STUDENT)); but it wouldn't work

Comment: Move the malloc just before the sscanf and do 'studentArr[count] = (STUDENT*) malloc(sizeof(STUDENT));'

Answer (score 0):

Some more problems:

1. `count` should be initialised to 0 not 1 because your array is zero-indexed.
2. You're not incrementing `count` in your loop
3. Allocate memory for each student inside the loop with `studentArr[count] = new Student();`
4. Prefer `strtok` to sscanf` to split the buffer into fields. Much easier to deal with the comma following the string.